# What is the best way to serialize xml into appropriate objects when versioned by namespaces?

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, xml-serialization

My question is the following.

I have xml that is versioned by a namespace.  I want to serialize this received xml into the appropriate object, but the only way I know to do this means I have to process the xml two times.  First to discover the namespace, and then in order to serialize to the object of the proper type based on the discovered namespace.  This seems dreadfully inefficient to me, and there must be some way using generics or something to get the appropriate type of object back without an 'if namespace == x then serialze to that' check.

Below is a sample of the only way I know to accomplish this.  Is there a better or more efficient way?

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod3()
        {
            //Build up an employee object to xml
            Schema.v2.Employee employee = new Schema.v2.Employee { FirstName = "First", LastName = "Last" };
            string xml = employee.ObjectToXml<Schema.v2.Employee>();

            //Now pretend I don't know what type I am receiving.
            string nameSpace = GetNamespace(xml);
            Object newemp;
            if (nameSpace == "Employee.v2")
                newemp = XmlSerializationExtension.XmlToObject<Schema.v2.Employee>(null, xml);
            else
                newemp = XmlSerializationExtension.XmlToObject<Schema.v1.Employee>(null, xml);

            // Check to make sure that the type I got was what I made.
            Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Schema.v2.Employee), newemp.GetType());
        }

        public string GetNamespace(string s)
        {
            XDocument z = XDocument.Parse(s);
            var result = z.Root.Attributes().
                    Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).
                    GroupBy(a => a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None ? String.Empty : a.Name.LocalName,
                            a => XNamespace.Get(a.Value)).
                    ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                 g => g.First());

            foreach (System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace item in result.Values)
                if (item.NamespaceName.Contains("Employee")) return item.NamespaceName;

            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public static class XmlSerializationExtension
    {
        public static string ObjectToXml<T>(this T Object)
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(Object.GetType());
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                s.Serialize(writer, Object);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
        public static T XmlToObject<T>(this T Object, string xml)
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                object obj = s.Deserialize(reader);
                return (T)obj;
            }
        }
    } 
}

namespace Schema.v1
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Employee", Namespace= "Employee.v1", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Employee
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace Schema.v2
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Employee", Namespace = "Employee.v2", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Employee
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

First, maybe don't do that at all. If you're serializing, prefer one method over the other unless the caller specifies a schema.

Second, don't parse the XML for discovery; just do string matching on "Employee.v2" and "Employee.v1" within (say) the first 100 bytes of the file (or however far you need to go to get the information). That should work, unless those are going to be common strings within your data.

Comment: Yes,  the caller is submitting the xml to me.  If no namespace then I need to use version 1, but if namespace is version 2, then the format of the xml and all the embeded elements can be drastically different.  Yes I can make another input method for the caller, but then interfaces change.

Comment: Second option as I think about it, seems to be a very good option, if there is no way to do this straight at the time of serialization.